# In siunitx, is there a possibility to use a decimal comma instead of a decimal point?

Tags: siunitx

There is no way for this

```
$\SI{-0,8}{\meter\per\square\second}$
```

to produce a , instead of a . and for there to be a `\cdot` between the units?

(I have no idea how to show rendered LaTeX text here.)

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by `\cdot` between the units? Do you mean when writing `\SI{2}{\newton\metre}`, you would get `2 N·m` (with the \cdot in between `N` and `m`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
     output-decimal-marker = {,},
     inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}
        }
\begin{document}
   $\SI{-0,8}{\meter\per\square\second}$
\end{document}
```

will compile to

[image]